# Filling a UITextField with a UIPickerView option immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

My app uses `UITextField`s which are populated by `UIPickerView`s, such as the screenshot attached. An example of how these are set up is below.

Currently, when tapping on the `UITextField`, it brings up the `UIPickerView`, but the field itself isn't populated until the `UIPickerView` is scrolled (e.g., to get the `UITextField` populated with "Yes, surgery" in the below example, the user must first scroll to "Yes, PCI <6h ago", and then back up again).

How do I get this so as soon as the `UITextField` is tapped the first row of the `UIPickerView` is used to populate the field?

```
let prevCardiacIntervPickerView = UIPickerView()  
prevCardiacIntervPickerView.delegate = self  
prevCardiacIntervPickerView.tag = 1  
prevCardiacIntervPickerField.inputView = prevCardiacIntervPickerView  
var prevCardiacIntervPickerOption = ["Yes, surgery", "Yes, PCI <6h ago", "Yes, PCI >6h ago", "No"]  
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}  
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return prevCardiacIntervPickerOption.count
        }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[row]
        }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            prevCardiacIntervPickerField.text = prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[row]
        }
}
```

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you fill UITextField with prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[0] in viewDidAppear Itself ?

Comment: @Rizwan if possible, I'd like the UITextField to remain empty until the user has tapped on it... If not then yes I guess this would be the best way forward, thanks.

Comment: In the textfield delegate `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, assign `textfield.text = prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[0]`

Comment: @chumps52 - see the alternative method in answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method.

**Set delegate**

```
yourTextfield.delegate = self
```

**Implement delegate method**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


     if (textField == yourTextfield) {  

        // your logic goes here...
        yourTextfield.text = prevCardiacIntervPickerOption.first

     }

   return true
}
```

Comment: Ended up using this as it worked better, just tweaked it slightly... if (textField == prevCardiacIntervPickerField && prevCardiacIntervPickerField.text?.count == 0) {
            prevCardiacIntervPickerField.text = prevCardiacIntervPickerOption.first
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can modify following function to

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if row.index == 1 && textField.text.count == 0 {
            // set titleForRow to the UITextField
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[row]
        }
}
```

There is a check that if `UITextfield` is yet **empty** and `row.index` is **one** then value of `titleForRow` should get populated in designated `UITextfield`

Other quick solution could be, fill `UITextField` with `prevCardiacIntervPickerOption[0]` in `viewDidAppear` itself. But in this case `UITextfield` will come populated with default value of first array element. If you want to keep `UITextfield`empty untill its selected once then go for first solution.

Comment: How does this populate the text field when the picker hasn't scrolled yet?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - I think this method is called when pickerView's rows itself are populated not when it is scrolled.

Comment: Ah yes... my bad. I did not check the delegate method properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not such a good Idea to have a `UITextField` be used in correlation with a picker, I mean, if the options are only selectable, then why allow free text? you could just used a selectable row to open the picker and have a default value.

But if you need this exact behavior, I would set a delegate on my textfield and check if it's empty on the first press:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  if textField == myTextField && !textField.text {
     textField.text = pickerViewDataSource[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: What would the alternative to a UITextField be? I searched online and that was the most common option that I saw - I don't want users to be able to type something in themselves, only the options I provide should be allowed.

Comment: Depends on your implementation... for example if you have a `TableView` I would set one of the cells to have a two `UILabels`, one for "label" AKA "Prev. cardiac ..." and one for the "value" AKA the picker list, and then I would listen to the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` that belongs to the `UITableViewDelegate`, on that click I would open the picker (after off course setting a default first value in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`), and on the `pickerViewDidSelectRow` I would update that certain value.

Comment: a second option, if I have a scrollview or just a view, I would have probably created a custom View, with two `UILabels` and a Custom `UIButton` as an overlay button, a custom `UIButton` can be transparent, and set on the whole view, so upon clicking on said button, it will simulate a click on the whole view, I would then listen to the click and manipulate the data I need, I'll to create an example later on today, I'll to post it by the end of the day on github and send you the link

Comment: Thanks! I'll experiment with different options :)